# PHP fgetcsv fails while explode works fine

Tags: php, explode, fgetcsv

Parsing a CSV file for getting an array some lines are not parsed correctly with fgetcsv; tried with "100", "0" and "1000" line length while the csv file lines were smaller than 80 chars; The separator char was ";":

```
fgetcsv($h, 0, ";");
```

I did the same with explode and everything works fine:

```
$line = fgets($handle);
$pieces = explode(";", $line);
```

I will use the latest, but, still, I would like to understand what was wrong with `fgetcsv`. Any idea?

Here more details:

**CODE**

```
$h = fopen(FCPATH . $file_dir, "r");
$handle = fopen(FCPATH . $file_dir, "r");

$header = fgetcsv($h, 0, ";");
$line = fgets($handle);

while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) { 

    $line = fgets($handle);
        log_message('error', "\n-----------START-------\n\t". print_r($line,1)); 
        log_message('error', "\n\t". print_r($data,1)); 
    $pieces = explode(";", $line);
        log_message('error', "\n\t". print_r($pieces,1)."\n-----------END---------\n\n");
//... other code
}
```

**LOG OUTPUT**

**many lines parsed correctly like this**

RIGHE DATI

```
ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
-----------START-------
2538;;;Emergency Contraception;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMyOSZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;;;;ellaOne;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMzMCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;pills;;;;;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-s.jpg;;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-m.jpg;Emergency Contraceptive: ellaOne Pill;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-l.jpg;;;Y;0;GBP;œ;8995;;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjExNiZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;Emergency Contraception<br>;;ellaOne 30mg x 2;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/hra-pharma-logo.jpg;HRA Pharma;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-t.jpg;

ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
Array
(
[0] => 2538
[1] =>
[2] => 
[3] => Emergency Contraception
[4] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMyOSZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => ellaOne
[9] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMzMCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[10] => pills
[11] => 
[12] => 
[13] => 
[14] => 
[15] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-s.jpg
[16] => 
[17] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-m.jpg
[18] => Emergency Contraceptive: ellaOne Pill
[19] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-l.jpg
[20] => 
[21] => 
[22] => Y
[23] => 0
[24] => GBP
[25] => œ
[26] => 8995
[27] => 
[28] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjExNiZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[29] => Emergency Contraception<br>
[30] => 
[31] => ellaOne 30mg x 2
[32] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/hra-pharma-logo.jpg
[33] => HRA Pharma
[34] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-t.jpg
[35] => 
)

ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
    Array
(
[0] => 2538
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => Emergency Contraception
[4] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMyOSZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => ellaOne
[9] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjMzMCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[10] => pills
[11] => 
[12] => 
[13] => 
[14] => 
[15] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-s.jpg
[16] => 
[17] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-m.jpg
[18] => Emergency Contraceptive: ellaOne Pill
[19] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-l.jpg
[20] => 
[21] => 
[22] => Y
[23] => 0
[24] => GBP
[25] => œ
[26] => 8995
[27] => 
[28] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjExNiZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[29] => Emergency Contraception<br>
[30] => 
[31] => ellaOne 30mg x 2
[32] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/hra-pharma-logo.jpg
[33] => HRA Pharma
[34] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/ellaone-t.jpg
[35] => 

)

-----------END---------
```

**Some lines not parsed correctly by fgetcsv, but still parsed correctly by explode, as in this case**

```
ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
-----------START-------
7667;;;Diabetes;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1MCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;;;;Metformin;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1MyZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;pills;Teva;;;;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-s.jpg;;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-m.jpg;;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-l.jpg;Large view of sealed box pack that contains Metformin 500mg tablets. ;;Y;0;GBP;œ;2995;;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjQ1MCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU;Diabetes<br>;;Metformin 500mg x 168;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/pfizer_logo.gif;Pfizer Pharmaceutical;http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-t.jpg;

ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
Array
(
[0] => 1686
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => Erectile Dysfunction
[4] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1NCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => Cialis
[9] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1NSZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[10] => pills
[11] => Lilly
[12] => 
[13] => Cialis (tadalafil) is a fast acting prescription treatment for men suffering with erectile problems
[14] => Cialis (tadalafil) is a prescription impotence treatment that helps men with erectile problems. Cialis helps men to get an erection and sustain an erection, working in a little as 30 minutes. Cialis is the longest lasting impotence medication, with benefits experienced for up to 36 hours.
[15] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/cialis-s.jpg
[16] => 
[17] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/cialis-m.jpg
[18] => 
[19] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/cialis-l.jpg
[20] => Cialis medication is sealed inside a box for better protection.
[21] => 
[22] => Y
[23] => 0
[24] => GBP
[25] => œ
[26] => 18495
[27] => 
[28] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjM3NiZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[29] => Impotence<br>
[30] => 
[31] => Cialis 10mg x 12
[32] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/lilly-
)

ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> 
Array
(
[0] => 7667
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => Diabetes
[4] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1MCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => Metformin
[9] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxMjI1MyZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[10] => pills
[11] => Teva
[12] => 
[13] => 
[14] => 
[15] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-s.jpg
[16] => 
[17] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-m.jpg
[18] => 
[19] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-l.jpg
[20] => Large view of sealed box pack that contains Metformin 500mg tablets. 
[21] => 
[22] => Y
[23] => 0
[24] => GBP
[25] => œ
[26] => 2995
[27] => 
[28] => http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlkPTcxNjQ1MCZhaWQ9NTQ1NDI0MjU
[29] => Diabetes<br>
[30] => 
[31] => Metformin 500mg x 168
[32] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/pfizer_logo.gif
[33] => Pfizer Pharmaceutical
[34] => http://www.euroclinix.net/en/images/product/metformin-pack-t.jpg
[35] => 

    )

-----------END---------
```

Comment: you need to give your CSV source

Comment: Give a proper example of data with which this happens.

Comment: And more code on how you use it.  this `fgetcsv($h, 0, ";");` isn't enough to find the issue.  `some lines are not parsed correctly with fgetcsv` whats this mean, do you have `\;` in your file. or `"words; words";"foo"` for example.

Comment: thank you. I added details and here it is available the csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/umpm2dzkx01m9vs/1%20-%20TEST%20NEW%20PRICES%20euroClinix%20-%201%202%20---%209.csv?dl=0

Comment: Please explain what exactly the difference are, resp. what data you are actually missing. I don’t know what to make of these two logs when you say one is for when things go correctly and the other is for when it’s not, yet both have lines saying `ERROR - 2019-02-16 19:21:47 --> ` … You should be able to reduce this to one problematic input line or a few at best, instead of just dropping your whole CSV data here with a “you go figure it out” undertone.

Comment: yes exactly. I added the CSV link because somebody was asking. But as you can see the log report exactly 2 lines: the first is not problematic, the secon is problematic. Then there is the parsing outcome for each of the two: parsing with fgetcsv and parsing with explode. Summarising

Comment: 1. the not problematic original line is this "2538;;;Emergency Contraception;http://track.hea[....]" and as you can see the 2 following arrays are identtical and correclty report the field in the CSV line (separated by ";")

Comment: 2. the second line, the problematic one, starts with "7667;;;Diabetes;http://track.healthtrader.com/track.php?c=cmlk". As you can see the 2 following arrays obtained respectively wth fgetcsv and with explode are very different and it appears imemdiatly thet the fgetcsv is corrupted. For instance the first field is the product ID the value of which is 7667 (you can see in the rough CSV line). But the fgetcsv gives 1686 as first array element. That's the point.

Comment: I don't know if this explanation was useful, but just to say that the log reports exactely one not problemati and one problematic original rough csv line and the result of parsing with the two PHP functions.

Comment: If your debug output starts with `1686` and `Erectile Dysfunction` , then this can hardly be reading even the correct line to begin with - to get from `7667;;;Diabetes;http://…` to _those_ values is not a failure to read something correctly within a single line, that is a mess-up across multiple lines.

Comment: So what happens when you put just one single of those problematic lines into a new file, and try to read that?

Comment: 1000 characters is just too low a limit, you have lines in there that are longer than that. I modified your code to compare the number of elements in the resulting arrays for each “line” and show a debug output when those differ - as long as I leave the 1000 in the fgetcsv line, I get such debug outputs, but as soon as I change that to 10000 (or 0 for no limit), I get no more such debug outputs, which means all of those line arrays had the same amount of elements, read either way, fgetcsv or fgets+explode …

Comment: I tried with 0 (that should mean lines with whatever length, no length limit), 1000 and 10000. It doesn't change. 
I had the same feeling that the problem could be in the previous line and for sure I can test the single problematic one and the ones immediately before. But still, if the problem was just the corruption of the previous lines, why does it work with explode function? 
Finally, what I wrote is just one case; in others, it seems that one line is split as it was generating multiple array entries. The explode function even in these cases works properly. Mistery!